# wxWidgets wxFrame resize in wxNotebook

Tags: visual-c++, wxwidgets

I am using wxWidget to design GUI. My GUI has multiple tabs. If user resizes the Frame, if he has selected some tab, when he is switching between tabs same modified size should be maintained. i am using sizers to put all child windows.But currently this is not happening. My current code is like this

```
void XTab::OnPageChanged(wxNotebookEvent & event)
{
    if(isActive())
    {
    int page = event.GetOldSelection();
    if(page!=-1)
    {
        XPanel * panel = (XPanel*)GetPage(page);
        xdmlASSERT(panel->isActive());
        panel->onUIDeactivate();
    }
    page = event.GetSelection();
    if(page!=-1)
    {
        XPanel * panel = (XPanel*)GetPage(page);
        xdmlASSERT(!panel->isActive());
        panel->onUIActivate();
    }
    RecalcSize();
    DFrame::UpdateLayout(this);
```

}

}

where DFrame is derived from wxFrame and XPanel is derived from wxPanel.The size is recalculated and best size is queried in GetSizer->CalcMin() method. This happens in ReCalcSize(). I don't know the reason why size of frame set by user is not persisting. Is there any way to store modified size of all children dynamically so? can u send some code for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [wxFrame resizing in wxNotebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937980/wxframe-resizing-in-wxnotebook)

Comment: please ask one question.  You can edit your question to make it clearer.